# Are US citizens legally required to provide a current address on a US customs declaration?

Tags: usa, legal, customs-and-immigration, paperwork

When returning to the USA, US citizens are required to fill out a written customs declaration. This form has space for a "Street Address". See a [sample form](https://www.cbp.gov/sites/default/files/assets/documents/2016-Jun/CBP%20Form%206059B%20%280316%29%20-%20Fillable_ENGLISH_0.pdf).

Are US citizens legally required to fill out the Street Address portion of the form? What are the consequences of refusing to provide an address?

Comment: One question I would ask is why would this be a concern?

Comment: This question is really about US civil rights and is only tangentially related to travel. It is not a good fit for this site IMHO.

Comment: Given all the other information on the form, why is it the street address you are concerned about?

Comment: If this question gets closed, you can contact CBP directly via https://help.cbp.gov/app/ask

Comment: Are you sure this is a "customs" form and not an "immigration" form?

Comment: If this is closed I suggest editing it to be more like "Do I have to put my address on the US immigration form?" or "What happens if I don't have an address to put on the US customs and immigration form?" etc.

Comment: I fail to see why this isn't a travel question. If it gets closed, I will vote to reopen immediately.

Comment: Why the "US citizens" part of this? Everyone has to fill out the blue card. And it's harder to answer the question when you don't live there. Or is your logic that citizens can't be refused entry even if they don't fill out the form completely?

Comment: @Andra did you know that on the new Review tab you can vote "Do not close" on questions with close votes against them?

Comment: @KateGregory I don't think those votes have any effect.

Comment: @phoog "a sufficient number of "Do Not Close" responses (currently 5) will kick the question out of the review queue and start aging the close votes" https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145071/difference-between-not-sure-and-do-not-close-in-review

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Arguably, no.  What if you don't have an address? What if you've just moved back? [They cater for that](http://www.cbp.gov/linkhandler/cgov/travel/clearing/traveler_entry_form/cbp_traveler_brochure.ctt/cbp_traveler_brochure.pdf) and assume you're staying *somewhere* - and as a result, hotel addresses are acceptable.

So if you wanted to legally dodge it without any possible problems, book a night at a hostel, and use that hostel's address on the form.

As for refusing, I've seen people try, and it doesn't work. The border guys want an address.  However, it's just process - I've seen one backpacker literally turn and ask anyone behind in the queue if they know the address of a hotel, and someone named the one from Pretty Woman on Rodeo Drive.  So he wrote that in, and handed it to the border guard, who shrugged, stamped, and completed the process.

Comment: Many countries have this and as I travel without plans I always get stumped. Japan is such a country. Once I had a business card or brochure somebody gave me for a hostel so I put that in even though I didn't stay there. I *have* been questioned at c&i when I've left it blank. And I once missed a bus because when I put my friend's hometown far far away that I intended to hitchhike to over several days, the c&i people seemed to be concerned that it might be too far to get to at that time of day and I might not know what I was in for... but I still got in OK (-:

Comment: I have twice entered One Microsoft Way as the address and was not given any issue about that. I didn't know where I was staying that night, but I knew what company I was visiting :-)

Comment: Maybe we should all start using the Stack Exchange office's address for this! (-;