# Filling US Customs and Border Protection form when a RV will be rented

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration

I am a Brazilian, and I will travel with my wife and son to spend some days in California.

I will arrive in Dallas and take an internal flight to San Francisco. I will rent a RV (Recreational Vehicle) in San Francisco, and I will travel across California (Yosemite Park, Los Angeles, Disneyland, Monterrey).

After 8 days, I will spend 3 days in San Francisco in an Airbnb.

What address should I use in the Customs and Border Protection form, field 4?

[image]

Comment: Have you decided where you will park the RV the first night?

Comment: Do you plan to sleep in the RV every night in the US?

Comment: I am planning to sleep at 8 nights in RV. The first night, I am planning to sleep at a Walmart. The second night, I will travel to Yosemite. However, I am going to US in February and I cannot make a reservation at Yosemite park in the period that I will be there.

Comment: @MarcelP. you will sleep at a Walmart...?

Comment: @JaneDoe1337 U.S. Walmarts often allow RVs to park in their lots at night.

Comment: @JaneDoe1337 Overnight parking of RVs at Walmarts is relatively common and many Walmarts allow this.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany & sourav Haha I'm sorry, I understood it as the night before the RV and imagined him sleeping inside a Walmart.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/46492/3221

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The reason Border Protection want this is so they can check up on whether you are really there, or going there. (It's rarely used, of course). Putting the address of a Walmart won't help that.

My recommendation is to put the address of the place you are renting the RV from. Then, when you get to the border officer, tell them your plans and tell them why you put that address and ask if that's what they wanted. It's 99.9% likely that will be fine, and the worst case is that they ask you to fill in the form again.

Comment: Agree with this.  The rental company will at minimum be able to confirm to the CBP that you picked up the RV as expected.  If you have a phone that works in the US you have probably already given that number to the rental company as well, so technically they would be able to locate you.  Although as DJClayworth says, the chances are very slim that it will be needed.

Answer (score 15):

I would just put the address of the first place you have reserved to stay.  If you have made reservations at camp sites, you could put down the address of the first one you will be staying.  If you don't have any set plans until you arrive at the AirBnB, I would put that address down.

This is not a big deal; not having a clear correct answer to this question is quite common (see this [related question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11254/your-address-at-destination-what-if-you-dont-know-any-address)).

The immigration agent at the border may ask you about your plans, in which case you can simply explain them. The address is very unlikely to be a concern, as long as it is a place you are legitimately staying, and you can provide some documentation/information showing your plans (for example showing your reservation for the RV may be helpful).